# Trouble plotting Maple space curve given a parametrization

Tags: vector-analysis, maple

I am being asked to plot a curve C with parametrization $$ r(t)=\left \langle \sin(mt)\cos(nt), \sin(mt)\sin(nt), \cos(mt) \right \rangle $$
with parameters of $$0\leq t\leq 2\pi$$
with integers $m=5$, $n=11$. 
I'm supposed to use the package `Student[VectorCalculus]` and the command SpaceCurve.

After typing in

```
helix := <(sin(5*t)*cos(11*t), sin(5*t)*sin(11*t), cos(5*t))>
SpaceCurve(helix, t = 0 .. 2*Pi)
```

my end result is this [Space Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf69S.png).

I do not know if I am doing this right, or if the curve is supposed to look like this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks correct. All you need is to add the option `numpoints` to get a finer plotting. I found $2000$ to give a decent smooth plot while not being too heavy on the calculation.

```
SpaceCurve(helix, t = 0 .. 2*Pi, numpoints=2000);
```